# Can astro components be globally available?

Tags: astrojs

I have a couple of astro components and I would like to avoid importing them every single time I write content in a `.mdx` just like this.

```
import Note from '@components/Note.astro';
```

Is there any way to make component Note globally available and not having to import manually every time? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up with the [`astro-auto-import` integration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/astro-auto-import).

1. Install the dependency:

   ```bash
   npm i astro-auto-import
   ```
2. Add it to your `astro.config.mjs`:

   ```js
   import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
   import AutoImport from 'astro-auto-import';
   import mdx from '@astrojs/mdx';

   export default defineConfig({
     integrations: [
       AutoImport({
         imports: [
           // Add your Note component to the auto-imports:
           '@components/Note.astro',
         ],
       }),

       // Make sure the MDX integration is included AFTER astro-auto-import
       mdx(),
     ],
   });
   ```